# How can I have pandoc render \lbrack and \rbrack in a .tex file to as actual brackets in a .docx file?

Tags: latex, pandoc, brackets, citations

I am trying to convert my PhD thesis, written in LaTeX, to a .docx file for my supervisor to edit. So far, all seems in order, except for the commands `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` in LaTeX which I use for references to the page number of an original work if I am citing translations. `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` are simply not visible in the .docx file (instead I see inverted question marks).

Here is the code of my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{gensymb}

%Degree Character
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\degree}

%Citations
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./library.bib}

\begin{document}

\author{author}
\title{Time and the Planetary}
\date{\today}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{./Introduction}
\include{./chapter01}
\include{./chapter02}
\include{./chapter03}
\include{./Conclusion}

\backmatter

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here is the code I use in the terminal to run pandoc:

`pandoc -s --bibliography library.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc --csl chicago-fullnote-bibliography-with-ibid.csl TimeAndEarth.tex -o test.docx`

Does anybody know how I can have pandoc render '\lbrack' as a [ ?

Comment: perhaps choose a font in your docx file that contains those characters?

Comment: mb21, thank you for your suggestion. This does not work, shamefully. Moreoever, if I choose another citation style (like chicago-author-date-with-ibid.cls), the inverted question marks do not appear at all. Instead I just see a space.